# php select option programming

Tags: php, mysql

How I can tell in php if they answer the questions 1,2,3,5,6 with YES the let out "the answer A"
if they answer the questions 1,3,5,10,12 with YES let out "the answer B"
in other cases, let out "the answer C"

```
    <form action="questions".php" method="POST">
<p>1.Question1?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<p>2.Question2?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<p>3.Question3?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<p>4.Question4?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<p>5.Question5?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<p>6.Question6?</p>
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
7.Question7?
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
8.Question8?
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
9.Questione9?
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
10.Question10?
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
11.Question11?
<p><select> <option value="YES">YES</option> <option value="NO">NO</option> </select></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /> </form>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your question. What is the current code for `questions.php`?

Comment: An questions about the provided answers or did one work for you?

Comment: for chris85 - everything is clear. This is the best solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of how this could be done using selects. I think radio buttons would be a better usage here.

```
<form method="POST" action="questions.php">
            <p>1.Question1?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[1]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>2.Question2?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[2]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>3.Question3?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[3]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>4.Question4?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[4]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>5.Question5?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[5]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>6.Question6?</p>
    <p>
        <select name="questions[6]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    7.Question7?
    <p>
        <select name="questions[7]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    8.Question8?
    <p>
        <select name="questions[8]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    9.Questione9?
    <p>
        <select name="questions[9]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    10.Question10?
    <p>
        <select name="questions[10]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    11.Question11?
    <p>
        <select name="questions[11]">
            <option value="YES">YES</option>
            <option value="NO">NO</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and then to process on the PHP side...(I'm also not sure how your conditions work, here is one way it could be done.)

```
foreach($_POST['questions'] as $key => $question) {
        switch($key) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                if($question == 'YES') {
                    echo 'the answer A';
                } else {
                    echo 'the answer C';
                }
            break;
            case 4:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                if($question == 'YES') {
                    echo 'the answer B';
                } else {
                    echo 'the answer C';
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Question #1=YES<br />Question #2=NO<br />Question #3=NO<br />Question #4=NO<br />Question #5=NO<br />Question #6=NO<br />Question #7=NO<br />Question #8=NO<br />Question #9=NO<br />Question #10=NO<br />Question #11=NO<br />
```

Comment: You could put a name in those brackets, like `name="questions[1]"`, `name="questions[two]"`, `name="questions[3]"` and probably might be a good idea to add selected to the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to the select for example:

```
echo "<select name='questionOne'>";
echo "<option value='YES'>YES</option>";
echo "<option value='NO'>NO</option>";
echo "</select><br/>";
echo "<select name='questionTwo'>";
echo "<option value='YES'>YES</option>";
echo "<option value='NO'>NO</option>";
echo "</select><br/>";
```

Then just do a conditional test:

```
if($_POST['questionOne'] == 'YES')
{
//do something
}
elseif($_POST['questionOne'] == 'NO')
{
//do something else
}
```